# Excel 2007 automation on top of a Windows Server 2008 x64 - NON SYSTEM USER

Tags: com, excel-2007, office-automation

Folks,

I have the exact same issue that's presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863864/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64), except that I'm trying automate Excel using a non-system (user) account.  The solution of creating a desktop folder doesn't work, because the user already has a desktop folder.  I can get the solution to work for the System Account just fine.  I can also get it to work for the Administrator account, when logged-in.  Is this in fact a Session 0/1 issue or is that still a red herring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Chase this down with SysInternals' ProcMon, probably the way Ogawa discovered his hack.  You'll drown in the data but you'll have to find the registry or file access that fails.  Ask more questions about it at superuser.com

Beware that this isn't just unsupported because of a missing file or registry key.  These Office programs were designed to be used interactively.  They'll put up a dialog when something goes wrong.  On a desktop where nobody can hear it scream.  Your service fails in a completely undiagnosable way, it just stops working and you cannot find out why.

Comment: Hi Hans - I set Application.Interactive=false, and Visible=false so I never see any dialogs (and also I'm super careful about what I do in excel).  It seems if this thing can work for LocalSystem it should be able to work for any arbitrary user.  I wish I had the time for ProcMon, but as you said, I'll be drowning in data.

Comment: I'll keep this Q open for a few days and see if anyone else responds