# exception from hresult 0x800a03ec error

Tags: c#-4.0, office-interop

While creating object of excel in c#

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

exception occurs as `exception from hresult 0x800a03ec`.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?  This exception is usually generated when you are accessing an invalid cell.

Comment: this is working in windows 2003 server but not in windows 2008 server with IIS7

Comment: Take a look at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/334c9f30-4e27-4904-9e71-abfc65975e23/problem-running-windows-service-with-excel-object-on-windows-server-2008-64-bit?forum=officesetupdeploylegacy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel 2007 automation on top of a Windows Server 2008 x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863864/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64)

Comment: Office version? Do you use the Click2Run edition of Microsoft Office?