# MS Access 2010, Excel 2010, Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit: SaveAs method of Workbook class failed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, windows-server-2008

Services used: MS Access 2010, Excel 2010, Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit)

In our MS Access database, we wrote a process that exports queries to .xlsx format and saves them on the network drive. It uses this syntax:

```
objxl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

and

```
xlWBk.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

where objxl is declared as:

```
Private objxl As Object
```

And files are opened via:

```
Dim xlWBk As Object

If objxl Is Nothing Then
    Set objxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

If Dir(sourceFile) = vbNullString Then
    Set xlWBk = objxl.Workbooks.Add
Else
    Set xlWBk = objxl.Workbooks.Open(sourceFile)
    blnFileExists = True
End If
```

This code works fine when we run it manually. I am reasonably confident that the code is correct, but I'm posting it here just in case.

However, we need to automate this database so we have it run from an account via scheduled task, set to run even if the account is not logged in (and this account has admin rights, etc). Unfortunately, when running the program like this, we get this error in our logs:

```
"SaveAs method of Workbook class failed."
```

We've verified that it isn't a network read/write problem (it writes all sorts of other files, such as .txt and .pdf, just fine to the network drive. This issue appears to be localized to Excel).

We've tried a fix as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090864/5239568

But nothing seems to be working so far.

Comment: *Did* you try saving to a local folder? Does it give the same error?

Comment: @Andre451 Yes, same error on local folder.

Comment: @HansUp Yes. The processes work correctly when run manually on the same machine.

Comment: Sounds like a a security setting that interdicts scripts and automated COM objects, but not manual actions: the leading suspect for that is 'Trusted Locations'.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it fixed. Here was what worked, in case anyone in the future has this same error.

We added BOTH folders:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to check for Excel add-ins that run automatically - especially a corporate security document classification / copyright notice script.

Your next suspect is **Trusted Locations**, which I've mentioned elsewhere under the heading [Trusted Locations: a source of misleading error messages](http://excellerando.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/trusted-locations-source-of-misleading.html).

This is the leading suspect, because 'Trusted Locations' is a security setting that interdicts scripts and automated COM objects, but not manual actions. Or at least, not *all* 'user is present' manual actions. So you won't catch it by trying to reproduce the error  manually - and you might find that your attempts at debugging give inconsistent results.

You can set a folder to be a trusted location manually, in any Microsoft Office Application, under the 'File' menus as Options; Trust Center; Trusted Locations - but this is user-specific and you might not be able to do it for whoever (or whatever) runs your application. So this should give you a hint about automating it:

#### VBA Code to set a Trusted Location:

```
Public Sub TrustThisFolder(Optional FolderPath As String, _
                           Optional TrustSubfolders As Boolean = True, _
                           Optional TrustNetworkFolders As Boolean = False, _
                           Optional sDescription As String)

' Add a folder to the 'Trusted Locations' list so that your project's VBA can
' open Excel files without raising errors like "Office has detected a problem
' with this file. To help protect your computer this file cannot be opened."

' Ths function has been implemented to fail silently on error: if you suspect
' that users don't have permission to assign 'Trusted Location' status in all
' locations, reformulate this as a function returning True or False


'  This should be used with caution: although I regard Microsoft's rationale
'  for 'Trusted Locations' to be flawed (in this specific case, perverse and
'  worse than ineffective) bypassing a security feature is never a good idea
'  without letting the users know what they are doing, and offering a choice

'  You are strongly advised to keep the confirmation dialogue, unless you've
'  run into something stupid - like refusing to open files in the user's own
'  local temp folder - which is what we're dealing with here, in basExcelSQL


' Author:

' Nigel Heffernan January 2015 http:\Excellerando.blogspot.com
'
' Based on code published by Daniel Pineault in DevHut.net on June 23, 2010:
' www.devhut.net\2010\06\23\vbscript-createset-trusted-location-using-vbscript\

' **** **** **** ****  THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN  **** **** **** ****

' This code has been widely published, and at least one of the sites carrying
' it (and derived works) asserts that it is subject to an open-source license,
' which explicitly forbids us from asserting ownership, copyright, or other
' intellectual property rights, or attempting to impose restrictive commercial
' secrecy terms on its use, re-use, or publication. Take care to label this
' this code, and segregate it from proprietary source code, or other material
' with embedded business process information which should be kept private.


' UNIT TESTING:
'
' 1:    Reinstate the commented-out line 'Debug.Print sSubKey & vbTab & sPath
' 2:    Open the Immediate Window and run this command:
'           TrustThisFolder "Z:\", True, True, "The user's home directory"
' 3:    If  "Z:\"  is already in the list, choose another folder
' 4:    Repeat step 2 or 3: the folder should be listed in the debug output
' 5:    If it isn't listed, disable the error-handler and record any errors


On Error GoTo ErrSub


Dim sKeyPath    As String

Dim oRegistry   As Object
Dim sSubKey     As String
Dim oSubKeys    ' type not specified. After it's populated, it can be iterated
Dim oSubKey     ' type not specified.

Dim bSubFolders         As Boolean
Dim bNetworkLocation    As Boolean

Dim iTrustNetwork       As Long
Dim bTempFolder         As Long

Dim sMsg    As String
Dim sPath   As String
Dim sDate   As String
Dim sDesc   As String
Dim i       As Long

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

bSubFolders = True
bNetworkLocation = False

If FolderPath = "" Then

    FolderPath = FSO.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path
    If sDescription = "" Then
        sDescription = "The user's local temp folder"
    End If
    
    bTempFolder = True
    
End If

If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
End If


sKeyPath = ""
sKeyPath = sKeyPath & "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\"
sKeyPath = sKeyPath & Application.Version
sKeyPath = sKeyPath & "\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations\"

 
Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
'   Note: not the usual \root\cimv2  for WMI scripting: the StdRegProv isn't in that folder
 
oRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath, oSubKeys
```

For Each oSubKey In oSubKeys
    sSubKey = CStr(oSubKey)
    oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath & "\" & sSubKey, "Path", sPath
    
    'Debug.Print sSubKey & vbTab & sPath
        
    If sPath = FolderPath Then
        Exit For
    End If
    
Next oSubKey
If sPath <> FolderPath Then
    If bTempFolder = False Then
        sMsg = ""
        sMsg = sMsg & "Microsoft Office will not allow " & APP_NAME & " to open files from this location: "
        sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        sMsg = sMsg & vbTab & "'" & FolderPath & "'"
        sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        sMsg = sMsg & "Would you like to add this folder to Microsoft Office's list or Trusted Locations?"
        
        Select Case MsgBox(sMsg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, APP_NAME & ": do you trust files from this location?")
        Case vbYes
            ' continue
        Case Else   ' Else captures cancel actions as well as an explicit 'No'
            Err.Raise -559038737, APP_NAME & ": TrustThisFolder", "user chose not to add folder to 'Trusted Locations'"
            Exit Sub ' This is dead code ...unless error-handling is bypassed. One day, you'll thank me for this.
        End Select
    End If
    If IsNumeric(Replace(sSubKey, "Location", "")) Then
        i = CLng(Replace(sSubKey, "Location", "")) + 1
    Else
        i = UBound(oSubKeys) + 1
    End If
    
    sSubKey = "Location" & CStr(i)
    
    If TrustNetworkFolders Then
        iTrustNetwork = 1
        oRegistry.GetDWordValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath, "AllowNetworkLocations", iTrustNetwork
        If iTrustNetwork = 0 Then
            oRegistry.SetDWordValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath, "AllowNetworkLocations", 1
        End If
    End If
    
    oRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath & "\" & sSubKey
    oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath & "\" & sSubKey, "Path", FolderPath
    oRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath & "\" & sSubKey, "Description", sDescription
    oRegistry.SetDWordValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sKeyPath & "\" & sSubKey, "AllowSubFolders", 1
    
    MsgPopup "Successfully added '" & FolderPath & "' to the Microsoft Office Trusted Folders list.", vbInformation, APP_NAME & ": Action confirmed.", 3
    
End If
ExitSub:
    Set oRegistry = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrSub:
    
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub

Note that this code is dependent on user intervention to confirm removing the 'Trusted Location' setting. You can remove the dialogues, but I'd urge you to consult your sysadmin before you do.

(Note: I'm using 'popup' dialogue boxes, which disappear automatically after a preset interval, allowing the code to continue. Ask if you want the code)

After that, it gets arcane. Here's the code I wrote for the last time I had to use a separate instance of Excel.exe to open a file:

```
With New Excel.Application

    .ShowStartupDialog = False
    .Visible = False
    .EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    .UserControl = False
    .Interactive = False
    .EnableEvents = False

    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    .Workbooks.Add  ' Calculation property is not available if no workbooks are open
    If .Calculation <> xlCalculationManual Then
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
 
    For i = .Workbooks.Count To 1 Step -1
        .Workbooks(i).Close False
    Next i


    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To .AddIns.Count
        If .AddIns(i).IsOpen Then
            .AddIns(i).Installed = False
        End If
    Next i


    For i = 1 To .COMAddIns.Count
        If .COMAddIns(1).progID Like "*Information*Classification*" Then
            ' no action
        Else
            .COMAddIns(i).Connect = False
            If Not .COMAddIns(i).Object Is Nothing Then
                .COMAddIns(i).Object.Close
                .COMAddIns(i).Object.Quit
            End If
        End If
    Next i
 
End With
```

You'll note the  `'On error Resume Next'`  in there: some Add-Ins can't be closed.

After that, it's phases of the moon and human sacrifice. Or, maybe, a quick look at the other answers on Stack Oveflow.

Comment: I'm looking at Trusted Locations currently -- should I be adding my input/output folders to this section and checking "allow trusted locations on my network" to test? I don't see any unusual Excel add-ins anywhere, either.

Comment: Yes, you should... Provided that you believe that these folders are in locations you can trust! It would be embarrassing to do this in a 'sandbox' folder, or an FTP drop receiving external files.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error even when enabling all the trust center folders/options/etc.

Comment: ...So what's with the answer *We added BOTH folders:'* ?   - It looks like adding a folder to Trusted Locations seems to have worked for you.